# django - QuerySet recursive order by method

Tags: python, django

I may have a classic problem, but I didn't find any snippet allowing me to do it.

I want to sort this model by its fullname.

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    parent   = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='child_set')
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def get_fullname(self):
        if self.parent is None:
            return self.name
        return u'%s - %s' % (unicode(self.parent), self.name)
    fullname = property(get_fullname)
```

1. I tried sorting by "parent", got *infinite loop error*. "parent__id" did not sort well.
2. I could not understand how to use *annotate()* for concatenating string fields.
3. I added a custom manager with *sorted()*, but it returns a list object and prevents my *forms.ModelChoiceField* to work.

Here's the sort

```
def all(self):
    return sorted(super(ProductTypeManager, self), key=lambda o: o.fullname)
```

What else is there in the djangonic jungle ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably create a denomalised field and order on that. Depending on your preferences you might wnat to override .save(), or use a signal to poplate the denormalised field.

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    parent   = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='child_set')
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    full_name     = models.CharField(max_length=128*4)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not full_name:
            self.full_name = self.get_fullname()
        super(ProductType, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_fullname(self):
        if self.parent is None:
            return self.name
        return u'%s - %s' % (unicode(self.parent), self.name)
```

Then do a normal order  by `full_name`

Comment: What if a parent changes its own name? You would need now to trigger a change in every child. Would not you?

Answer (score 1):

Or, if what you're trying to do is to generate a tree structure, have a look at [django-mptt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/). It also allows for ordering on a manually set order.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
ProductType.objects.alL().order_by('parent__name', 'name')
```

Comment: It behaves strangely, like order_by('parent__id') did.

Comment: What does "behaves strangely" mean, precisely?  Could you update your question with the specific thing it does wrong?

Comment: I meant, it does not sort well : http://pastebin.com/m3af438ac

It is known to be inconsistent : http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7101#comment:1

Answer (score 0):

agreed :

ProductType.objects.all().order_by('parent__name', 'name')

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields

Comment: What does "agreed" mean in this answer?  Could you fix it so that it's clear what you're agreeing with?

Comment: S.Lott, "could" is past tense. Can you please fix your comment?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely explore the route you mentioned as 1) above:

```
ProductType.objects.order_by('parent__name', 'name')
```

Why is it erroring with an infinite loop? Is your example data referencing itself?

Comment: It is a Django exception : 
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/sql/query.py?rev=11274#L1012

It is quickly explained here:
http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7101#comment:1